# Appending a line at the end of a file

Tags: vim, octave

Within VIM, I can execute Octave scripts via this mapping:

```
map <F6> :w<CR>:!run-octave -q % <CR>
```

However, as I recently discovered, Octave doesn't show any plots unless there is a "pause" command at the end of a script.

How can I map F6 so this pause command is added automatically each time I invoke the key?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may not be the best way to handle running Octave scripts from Vim, see below for an alternative.

#### The requested solution

To accomplish what you want, define the following function somewhere:

```
function! RunOctave()
  let save_cursor = getpos('.')
  call append(line('$'), "pause")
  write
  execute "!run-octave -q " . expand('%')
  $delete _
  write
  call setpos('.', save_cursor)
endfunction
```

And define a mapping to call it:

```
map <F6> :w<CR>:call RunOctave<CR>
```

#### A better approach

I started out by running Octave similar to the above, but as I tend to use slow computers this is  not a good solution for me. I have instead configured Vim to remote-control an instance of Octave.

This can be done through a terminal multiplexer, similar to what [I suggested for Matlab here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12307838/1331399), e.g.:

```
tmux new-session -s octave "octave -q"
```

For optimal flexibility, I want to be able to evaluate single lines in octave from Vim:

```
imap <buffer> <F1> <Esc>:!tmux send-keys -t octave "<C-r>=getline('.')<CR>"<C-r>=nr2char(13)<CR><CR>a
nmap <buffer> <F1>      :!tmux send-keys -t octave "<C-r>=getline('.')<CR>"<C-r>=nr2char(13)<CR><CR>
```

Evaluate visual selections:

```
vmap <buffer> <F2> call ExecSelection()<CR><CR>
```

Which depends on the following function:

```
let s:octave_selection = '/var/tmp/vim_octave_selection.m'

function! ExecSelection()
  if line(".") == line("'<'")
    exec ".write! " . s:octave_selection
  else
    exec ".write! >> " . s:octave_selection
  endif

  if line(".") == line("'>")
    exec "!tmux send-keys -t octave 'run " . s:octave_selection . "'" . nr2char(13)
  endif
endfunction
```

And last, but not least, evaluate the whole file:

```
imap <buffer> <F3> <Esc>:!tmux send-keys -t octave "<C-r>=expand('%:t:r')<CR>"<C-r>=nr2char(13)<CR><CR>a
nmap <buffer> <F3>      :!tmux send-keys -t octave "<C-r>=expand('%:t:r')<CR>"<C-r>=nr2char(13)<CR><CR>
```

This last mapping requires that the current working directory for the buffer is the same as that of the Octave script.

Comment: The requested solution is good enough for me. It's indeed very handy especially going through 100-150 files in one sit.