# How to run matlab script multi-time without restarting the matlab?

Tags: matlab

I prefer using Matlab in command line.

As I know, the matlab script can be run in this way:

```
\> matlab < script.m
```

After I modified a parameter in `script.m`, I want to rerun it,
I have to:

```
\> matlab < script.m
```

The problem is there is redundant starting of matlab, which is
unnecessary. If you know JVM, it's similar to restarting JVM (`java MainClass`).

How to solve this?

Comment: What's wrong with making script.m a function and calling it with different parameters within script2.m, and running "$matlab < script2.m"?

Comment: Have a look at [this answer from Sam Roberts](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18782203/2778484), a MathWorks insider. However, the COM automation part only applies to Windows. Perhaps the Java to MATLAB (JMI) functionality could be used.

Comment: here is another solution: [Call a function by an external application without opening a new instance of Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18781803/call-a-function-by-an-external-application-without-opening-a-new-instance-of-mat)

Comment: Also consider writing a function that accepts your parameter as an input.

Answer (score 0):

Call `matlab.exe` from `{Root MATLAB}\bin\win64` or `win32` instead of the root folder to prevent multiple instances