# Matlab fails to run a script when scheduled with Task Scheduler

Tags: scheduled-tasks, matlab

I am trying to start Matlab and run a script scheduled at a specific time using the windows Task Scheduler.

If I use a scheduled task I can see Matlab starting, but this last fails to load the script and returns me the error below

```
??? Unexpected Matlab operator.
```

Do you know what it is and why?

I am using the following syntax

```
c:\app\matlab\bin\matlab.exe -r c:\MyURL\ScriptFile.m
```

If I load the script manually and run it it tells me that the file is not in the path so give ms a choice between

- Change Current Directory
- Add Folder to the Path

Either choices are fine and the script runs fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matlab is starting in its main directory and `-r` requires your function to be in quotation marks, thats why you get the error.

And you need to change to your workspace first, the syntax is as follows:

```
matlab -sd pathToYourWorkspace -r "function(parameters)"
```

Maybe you also want to avoid the complete loading of the whole Matlab working environment, so add at the end:

```
-nodesktop -nosplash
```

---

If you run your task sheduled, are you doing it multiple times? Are you aware that every function call like above opens a new instance of Matlab? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18781803/call-a-function-by-an-external-application-without-opening-a-new-instance-of-mat/18791964#18791964) may be helpful then.

---

From the comments: of course you could just use the command `run` to call a script wherever it is.

`"run('c:\MyURL\ScriptFile.m')"` is an example for `"functionName(YourArgs)"`

as `run` is a function and the string `'c:\MyURL\ScriptFile.m'` its argument. In this case it is usually not necessary to change the workspace before.

Comment: Your suggestion is correct - but the cause of the problem is actually that the "-r" argument is passed directly to MATLAB to be evaluated - so the error is what you'd see if you typed `c:\MyURL\ScriptFile.m` at the MATLAB `>>` prompt.

Comment: Hi. To run a script file I called  -r "run('c:\MyURL\ScriptFile.m')" while to call a function just call -r "functionName" or , if parameters are needed -r "functionName(YourArgs)".

Comment: @AbruzzoForteeGentile: `"run('c:\MyURL\ScriptFile.m')"` is an example for `"functionName(YourArgs)"` as `run` is a function an the string `'c:\MyURL\ScriptFile.m'` its argument ;)