# Call MATLAB from command line and keep it open for next processing - Linux

Tags: c, linux, matlab, command-line

I would like to call `MATLAB` from a software developed in C. I know how to call MATLAB, by using a system call using the standard syntax:

`matlab -nojvm`

My problem is that each time I spend a lot of time in opening a new session of `MATLAB`(when the requested processing ends, `MATLAB` closes, so I have to re-execute it when new data is ready for processing).

Is there any way to keep a MATLAB session always open (and use it as a "server"), and how to "inform" it that new data are available to be processed? This will avoid the pain of executing each time a new session of MATLAB, which is really time consuming.

Comment: This is called deaemonizing and can be done as described [here](http://www-theorie.physik.unizh.ch/~dpotter/howto/daemonize).

Comment: You only need to fully daemonize it (detach it from the shell) if the Matlab session/server has a different lifetime than the parent process.  It's not clear whether that is needed from the original description.

Comment: you could also have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306333/matlab-command-from-bash-command-line-on-an-already-running-session/12307838#12307838) or maybe even [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18781803/call-a-function-by-an-external-application-without-opening-a-new-instance-of-mat)

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB has an `input` function that listens to `stdin`. Consider the following script that waits for your upstream C program to enter the filename of a chunk of data it has written and flushed to disk:

```
while true()
    % wait for upstream process to enter filename
    filename = input('', 's');
    % quit means we're done
    if strcmp(filename, 'quit')
        quit()
    end
    % run secondary processing as instructed
    process_chunk(filename);
end
```

The C program can simply write the name of a data file to `stdout`. After the last chunk has been written, it can even tell the MATLAB script to terminate by saying `quit`. The C program, in essence, could look like this:

```
for (int n = 0; n < N_CHUNK; n ++)
{
    // generate a filename for this chunk
    char filename[32];
    sprintf(filename, "chunk%d.txt", n);
    // do the actual work, generating a data file
    write_chunk(n, filename);
    // tell MATLAB to process that file
    printf("%s\n", filename);
}
// tell MATLAB we're done
printf("quit\n");
```

To make both work together, the C program has to "type" into the MATLAB process. If the C program is named `foo` and the script is in `bar.m`, you chain them together like this:

```
$ foo | matlab -nojvm -nodisplay -r bar
```

I just tested this on MATLAB R2013a (8.1.0.604), but I would not be surprised if `input` has been listening to `stdin` for a long time, and if this works with virtually any version of MATLAB on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Mathworks provides some documentation and sample code on how to call Matlab from C, C++, and Fortran in their [Documentation Center](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/calling-matlab-engine-from-c-c-and-fortran-programs.html).  It looks like you can set Matlab variables and pass in arbitrary strings then read the results from other variables.

If you really do want to write to Matlab's `stdin` and `stdout`, probably the cleanest way would be to:

1. Call `pipe`(2) twice to create a read/write pair of pipes to connect to Matlab's stdin and stdout.
2. Call `fork`(2) to create a new child process.
3. In the child process, use `dup`(2) to

   1. Copy the read end of one pipe over file descriptor 0 (`stdin`), and
   2. Copy the write end of the other pipe over file descriptor 1 (`stdout`).
4. Have the child call `execve`(2) to invoke Matlab

The parent, can now write commands into the first pipe and they will be sent to Matlab.  You may have to call `flush` after each command depending on how you open and write to the pipe.  The second pipe, connected to Matlab's `stdout`, will capture the text output from Matlab.

I am not sure if Matlab sends anything to `stderr`.  If so and you want to capture it, create a third pipe tied to `stderr` (file descriptor 2).  Otherwise, it will go to your original program's `stderr`, which may or may not be what you want.

I have not used Matlab's C/C++ interface, but I would guess that using it is probably easier than trying to parse Matlab's output.