# Run exe in Matlab in for loop most efficiently

Tags: matlab

I wounder what is the most efficient way to run a program, given as executable, from Matlab many times in a for loop. At the moment I use the following Code:

```
for i = 1:100
    system('MyProgram.exe');
    % Do something with the output from the .exe
end
```

So, from the profiler I know that 99,9% of the time is used in the execution of the Program itself. My question is basically if there is a more efficient way to run executables in general from within Matlab?

I have read that everytime I run an exe like described above, a process is created which has to initialize the Matlab runtime environment... Is there possibly a way to avoid this by only doing the initialization once and from there on run the programm multiple times?

Comment: Hi, Could you tell me a little bit about the .exe file?  Is it a compiled Matlab executable?

Comment: Yes, it is a compiled SL model.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing your can't directly modify the .exe's you are given, so perhaps there is a way to instead of calling the .exe directly, you could call a .bash shell script.

I would imagine that if you do this and within the shell script check to see if a workspace is already open to associate the execution of the .exe with a specific process ID.  Although I would guess that when the executable finishes it closes the session.

Just throwing some stuff out there :P  I have had lots of trouble with how Matlab handles this kind of thing (Also things like Excel).

Hope you figure this out.

EDIT:  I found some possible examples here [Example Descriptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306333/matlab-command-from-bash-command-line-on-an-already-running-session/12307838#12307838)

-Kyle

Comment: Hm, yes when the executable finishes it closes the session, thats exactly the problem.

Comment: Yes, I can modify it

Comment: Is there a specific reason it has to be a .exe?  Is it possible to have the code executed within the Matlab script directly?